# WPF KeyBinding swallowing keys, preventing TextBox use

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

**Problem Overview:**
Any `KeyBinding`'s defined at a level higher than a `TextBox` (with no modifier keys assigned), prevents the user from typing those keys inside the `TextBox`.

**Minimal XAML Hierarchy:**

```
<Window>
  <UserControl>
    <Border>
      <UserControl>
        <TextBox>
```

**Minimal Command/KeyBinding:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.SomeCommand" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="A" Command="{StaticResource Commands.SomeCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource Commands.SomeCommand}" Executed="..." />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

The `Command` and `KeyBinding`, are defined at the **first** `UserControl` level. So in this example, in the textbox, the user can type freely until they press the `A` key, and then it just does not insert the letter into the textbox. I can clearly see that the `TextBox.KeyDown` and `TextBox.PreviewKeyDown` **are** firing when you press the `A` key (and `Handled = false`) , but the letter will not get added to the text of the textbox and `TextBox.PreviewTextInput` does **not** fire.

I'm looking for any suggestions that may indicate what is swallowing the keypress and stopping it from getting processed by the TextBox, or anything related to how I can debug this issue.

**EDIT:**
 Thanks to [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), I was able to clearly see the problem.

1. `TextBox.PreviewKeyDown` tunnels down and fires through the visual tree, starting at the Window, and ending at the TextBox
2. `TextBox.KeyDown` bubbles back up starting at the TextBox and heading towards the window
3. `TextBox.KeyDown` gets Handled set to true by the first UserControl that has the KeyBinding set.
4. `TextBox.PreviewTextInput` never fires, nor does the textbox process the input, because the KeyDown event was set as handled.

This still leaves the problem, how do you prevent the UserControl from handling the input if a textbox has focus? Within the Command execution, I can check if a textbox has keyboard focus, but by this time it's too late.

Comment: I believe [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com) has an option to monitor events.

Comment: @mnistic: Thanks for the suggestion, I was able to find some additional details and have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had used the [TextComposition RaiseEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136859/184746) approach for years, however this seems to break typing for non-latin keyboard layouts (eg. cyrillic).

The proper way to do this is to derive from InputBinding and return false in the `Matches?` check if the event originated from a text-box.

```
/// <summary>
/// This gesture doesn't handle keys originating in a text control. This allows key bindings without modifier keys
/// that don't break normal typing. A standard KeyGesture doesn't have such logic; this allows the parent of a
/// text box to handle such bare keypresses before the textbox gets to see it as normal text input, thus breaking
/// normal typing.
/// </summary>
public class BareKeyGesture : InputGesture
{
    public Key Key { get; set; }

    public override bool Matches(object targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)
    {
        var keyEventArgs = inputEventArgs as KeyEventArgs;
        if (keyEventArgs == null)
            return false;

        if (inputEventArgs.OriginalSource is TextBoxBase)
            return false;

        return (int)Key == (int)keyEventArgs.Key && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This only exists because the InputBinding constructor is protected, but since we have to have it anyway
/// we also use this opportunity to simplify adding a BareKeyGesture to it.
/// </summary>
public class BareKeyBinding : InputBinding
{
    private BareKeyGesture _gesture = new();

    public BareKeyBinding()
    {
        Gesture = _gesture;
    }

    public Key Key
    {
        get => _gesture.Key;
        set { _gesture.Key = value; }
    }
}
```

And now that you have an InputGesture which will ignore events originating from textboxes, you can use it in XAML like normal:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <nsp:BareKeyBinding Key="D" Command="{...}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextInput` and `PreviewTextInput` only fires when the Text actually changes / might change.

As you updated your question to reflect, the `Command` intercepts the event and the (Preview)TextInput events are never raised.

The nicest solution would be to add a modifier key to your KeyBinding, but I suspect that is not your preferred way to go.

Another option would be to `e.Handle` the PreviewKeyDown event on the TextBox and raise the TextComposition events yourself, using something like:

```
target.RaiseEvent(new TextCompositionEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, 
new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, "A")) 
{ 
    RoutedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent 
});
```

(Alternatively, insert into `textBox.Text` at the correct `CaretIndex`)

Truth be told, it would still be a hack.

Comment: I was trying to avoid handling the key presses myself in PreviewKeyDown because I thought it was going to be difficult to get right. I didn't know i could raise a textcomposition event myself though, it makes things easier - and I ended up implementing a solution using that, so i'm giving you the accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. 
I took a look to documentation for key bindind, and there is described, that the key on which you bind shouldn't be just key, but key gesture, so it shall be

- Modifier key + normal key
- Numeric keypad key
- Functional key.

Of course, it works with just A, but it's bad practice overall. You should consider to implement some of the posibilities mentioned behind. More at https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use `KeyBinding` this not going to work without major hacks. A solution I implemented for this is:

1. Use the `KeyDown` event to capture those keys being pressed (instead of `KeyBindings`). This will be on your code-behind and from there you'll need to switch on the pressed Key to call the required command (`SomeCommand` in your case).
2. Now you have a different problem. The `TextBox` is getting the input but your key-bound commands are also firing. On the code behind, check the type of `keyEventArgs.InputSource` and ignore the key stroke if it's a `TextBox`.

It should look like this:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ICommand command = null;

    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.A:
            command = Commands.SomeCommand;
            break;
        case Key.B:
            command = Commands.SomeOtherCommand;
            break;
    }

    bool isSourceATextBox = e.InputSource.GetType() == typeof(TextBox);
    if (command != null && !isSourceATextBox)
    {
        command.Execute(parameter:null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to hear the reasons for the downvote please.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In the original question we have a TextBox - and a parent component has a keybinding which is swallowing keypresses on the TextBox. The keybinding does not exist on the TextBox. In fact, the keybinding could be literally anywhere in the component tree above the TextBox. This is a 5 year old question, which already has a really really great answer which solves all of the problems of a parent compoenent swallowing key-presses in a textbox.

Comment: @caesay This is an alternative solution with its pros and cons, but for many people it will be the best option (it was my case, the solution works. Therefore, it's not wrong). The currently chosen answer has three big downsides: 1) requires extra code for each TextBox on the scope of the KeyBinding which means poor maintainability. 2) The KeyBinding Key needs to be referenced on each PreviewKeyDown. 3) As the answer's author himself said it: *it's a hack*.

Comment: This is also a hack, which like i said, does not work if you have parent components with KeyBindings

Comment: It's an alternative to using KeyBindings. Anyway I don't agree with you but now the rational behind the downvote is clear to me and to any other person looking into this in the future. Thank you :)

Comment: @caesay you may say this is a hack, but given my situation and requirements it's the tidiest I've seen ...

Comment: @Jammer You can have a look at my recent answer as to how you can achieve this while still using KeyBindings properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077265/184746

Comment: Ahhhhhh, neater, will have to take a closer look Thanks.